# .click executed twice on a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi ive got this html structure :

```
<div id="media1368131383" data-date="1368131383" class="gauche media" style="">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td valign="top" style="vertical-align:top !important;padding-right:7px;">
                    <a href="http://www.mupiz.com/johnwatsonmusic" target="_blank">
                        <img src="http://www.mupiz.com/37038/picture?type=square" width="44">
                    </a>
                </td>
                <td class="dcom vidCustomD" style="width:450px">
                    <a href="http://www.mupiz.com/johnwatsonmusic" target="_blank">John, Watson</a> a ajouté une nouvelle chanson
                    <br>
                    <a href="http://www.mupiz.com/johnwatsonmusic/dans-un-roman">«Dans un roman»</a>
                    <br>
                    <span class="media_date gris petit">il y a environ 20 jours</span>
                </td>
                <td align="right">
                    <div class="playerMedia" data-url="http://www.mupiz.com/mp3/37038/mp3_87526.mp3" data-id="mp3_87526.mp3">Dans un roman</div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <br>
</div>
```

ive attached an event click on .playerMedia, but it is executed twice. But when the .playerMedia is not on a table it is executed once,

Js (perfectly workin)

```
function InlinePlayer() {
    $(".playerMedia").each(function () {
        var nom = $(this).attr("data-id");
        nom = soundManager.createSound({
            id: $(this).attr("data-id"),
            url: $(this).attr("data-url")
        });
        $(this).live('click', function (e) {

            if (!$(this).hasClass("sm2_playing")) {

                nom.play();
                $(this).addClass("sm2_playing");
            } else {
                $(this).removeClass("sm2_playing");
            }


            debug("1 time");
            e.stopPropagation();
            return false;
        });
    });
}
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: And where's the javascript ?

Comment: This does not work, ive updated the code

Comment: Where does `InlinePlayer` get called ?

Comment: One time after an ajax request, it works if the div is outside of the table, i use jquery 1.7.2

Comment: yes i call the function on the window object, nom.play(); get no problems

Comment: How can i be sure that the function is executed only one time onclick ?

Answer (score 0):

Your InlinePlayer function is working correctly. The most likely problem is that you are calling it twice rather than once, attaching the click handler twice. The best solution is to not call InlinePlayer() more than once, but a quick and dirty solution using a global variable is shown below.

```
// global boolean that determines if InlinePlayer has already been called:
var inlinePlayerCalled = false;

/*
 * your code...
 */

function InlinePlayer() {
 // check if InlinePlayer has already been called
 // if it has not, then mark it as called.
if(inlinePlayerCalled) {
    inlinePlayerCalled = true;
    return false;
}
   ...
}
```